# Wordpress content workflow

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a simple content workflow system, where an item is submitted for review, and after reviewed it is published.  I can't use a post status because the old version has to be visible while the new one is in review.

I don't really want to have to create my own table to store this information, so I was thinking about using the revision system to add a revision what's marked with a post status of in review.  I would then show that in the review panel/edit page, but the one being displayed to users would still be the old one.  Once the review was successfully accepted, it'd replace the old one.

The issue is that I can't find any information on how to save a post being updated as a review; does anyone have any idea how this could be accomplished?

Thanks

Comment: Check if [Edit Flow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-flow/) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one turned out to be a tough cookie to crack, but I learned a lot of things I feel I should share for any other soul looking to replicate this functionality.

Firstly, you need to specify if the current post save is an update or a publish.  Aka is the post new, or not?  I thought of a clever little trick to check this:

```
$isNewPost = $data['post_date_gmt'] == $data['post_modified_gmt'];
```

The first hook I used was the `wp_insert_post_data` hook, which is called on the post object before it is inserted/updated in the database.  This hook is great, because it allows you to return nothing which cancels the insert to the database.  Of course you don't always want to do this, if the post is new then we should add it to the database, so there is a placeholder while it's in review, but instead of just adding it we set the post status to draft.  If it is an update, then we pass back nothing but add the review there.

Now, if the post is new, we need to also hook into the `post_updated` hook, because it's only then that we have an actual DB record, I save the ID passed in to the `wp_insert_post_data` record and use it to find the correct `post_saved` event, then adding the review post.

Wordpress is somewhat odd, whenever a new post screen is visited, a post is added to the database, of type auto-draft, then a few seconds of editing in another post is saved, a revision (if the post type supports it, which built in ones do), this also fires all the post save events.  Another issue I ran into was saving out the review post, because it would then trigger the `post_saved` and `wp_insert_post_data` hooks, causing an infinite loop.

There were a few other interesting issues, and if anyone is curious I'd be more than happy to help, sadly the code is proprietary as I wrote it for a company, perhaps I can convince them to open source it at some point (most likely not though, as we are under contracts with clients concerning privacy).

I might diagram the workflow, as I consider it complex enough to warrant it; and it might help others, this was definitely not a trivial problem to work out.

I will give one word of advice, if you are dealing with post meta (which trust me, they'll want you to, even if they initially said not to worry about it) make the review post the same post type as the post it's reviewing, and make it a child.  Save the original parent in post meta, along with any other information needed.  This way you don't have to deal with rebuilding the edit pages.